# Extract data from Prometheus and Loki with No Internet Connection

Tags: prometheus, grafana, offline, grafana-loki

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently facing a challenge where I need to perform an offline data dump from both Prometheus and Loki. The specific details are:

- We have access to the server of the customer.
- There is no internet connection available.
- The goal is to efficiently dump data from Prometheus and Loki into a file format.

I'm seeking guidance on a streamlined approach or tools that can facilitate this offline data dump process. The desired outcome is to have the extracted data stored in a file for further analysis.

Any insights, code snippets, or recommended methodologies for achieving this within the given constraints would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

I am not able to find efficient way to do it.

Comment: Prometheus can itself create a snapshot (essentially backup) of it's data. And later Prometheus can use that snapshot to recreate it's data. And Prometheus can obviously used for "further analysis". Is that what you need?

Comment: I actually wanted to dump the data from Prometheus in an offline manner for a particular timeframe. I know there are HTTP APIs which do that, but will I be able to extract data when there is no internet connection, but can access the other server in which Prometheus is running?

Comment: Yes you will. You can simply access api using localhost. And also you can query local prometheus with the tool called `promtool`. But nothing of this is on topic got SO.

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance.
Is there any way to do the same for Loki ad InfluxDB as well?